# Binding multiple input box values to a list

Tags: angularjs, pug

I have three input fields - Range1, Range2 and Range3 and an object called pconfig. I have a List named Range in this object. What I am trying to do is to bind these three input fields to this single list but so far I've failed to do so. Is there anyway I can do it using Angular in jade template?

```
        - for (count = 1; count < 4; ++count) {
          .form-group
            label Range #{count} 
            input.form-control(type='text' ng-model='pconfig.range' placeholder='Upper Range')                
        - }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you getting?

I don't know what language/script you are using. But I believe the `ng-model` name should be with array index for Array List.

```
type='text' ng-model='pconfig.range[#{count}]' placeholder='Upper Range'
```

(Not sure how to express `count` value there. Just a guess)

Comment: Hi Shiju,

I am using Jade template for my form, CoffeeScript as a controller and java to handle the request in backend. 
I am getting this error when form is submitted - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: I received the above mentioned error when tried ng-model='pconfig.range[#{count}]' as you suggested.

Comment: Issue is resolved! With your solution and some more digging into the code. This error was coming because there was something wrong with the object i was sending in request, so i changed the argument type to Object on the receiving end and it solved the problem. Thanks!